# Turing degrees that eventually jump to some $0^{(n)}$

Tags: logic, computability

Starting with any $A\subseteq \omega$, we can form a strictly increasing sequence of Turing degrees by taking iterated Turing jumps: $$A<_T A'<_T A'' <_T\dots.$$
By Post's theorem we also know that if $A$ is definable/arithmetic, there is some $n$ such that $0\leq_T A\leq_T 0^{(n)}$. This means that the jump sequences starting at $0$ and at $A$ are interleaved. My question is whether the two sequences eventually meet up:

Let $d$ be an arithmetic Turing degree (in other words $d\leq_T 0^{(n)}$ for some $n$). Are there some $k$ and $m$ such that $d^{(k)} \equiv_T 0^{(m)}$?

I suspect the answer is no. If we drop the definability assumption, I can prove that this fails by a forcing/absoluteness argument: if $c$ is a Cohen real over $L$ then no finite jump of $c$ (or even any reasonable infinitary jump) is in $L$ and cannot be equivalent to an iterated jump of $0$. By Shoenfield absoluteness, a degree with the same property must already exist in $L$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is correct: in fact, we can find a degree ${\bf d}$ between ${\bf 0}$ and ${\bf 0'}$ such that for all $n$, ${\bf d}^{(n)}$ is strictly between ${\bf 0}^{(n)}$ and ${\bf 0}^{(n+1)}$. This was first proved independently by Lachlan and Martin, but a simpler proof using the recursion theorem was found later by [Sacks](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-01/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7.pdf) (thus coming nicely full circle since Sacks posed the question originally). Perhaps confusingly, such degrees are often called "intermediate" since they are neither low$_n$ nor high$_n$ for any $n$.